# Table looks bad in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a table with a layout that I made. The layout looks well in Google Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.

This is how it's looks in Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

This is how it's looks in IE:

[image: IE]

This is the table's HTML code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46%" colspan="2"></td>
        <td style="width: 23%; padding-top: 0.5%" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td style="width: 23%; padding-top: 0.5%" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 23%" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td style="width: 23%" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 46%" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I resolve these layout differences?

Answer (score 0):

**You could try many things to fix this issue...**

Try adding the following "hacks" to your html page:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link href="/style/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
    <link href="/style/core.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

> This will force IE to use the rules you specify in **ie.css** so you can give it the rules you want there. This will also hide the other parts that are used in Google Chrome and Firefox from IE.

Instead of percentages, try using fixed pixel values like

```
<td style="width: 20px; padding-top: 20px;" rowspan="2">
```

> You can use the following site to validate your CSS to see if it meets
>   the W3C standards:
>
> http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
>
> It'll go though your CSS, check compatibility, and spit back errors if
>   they exist. It'll show you where in your file you have mistakes so you
>   can go fix them. I don't know about any tools that will fix your CSS
>   for you... I wouldn't use it though because I wouldn't learn anything
>   that way.
>
> You can use the following site to validate your HTML and other markup
>   languages you use:
>
> http://validator.w3.org/
>
> Using these tools will help you make cross-browser compatible
>   websites... if something is not compatible, you can use these tools
>   for debugging and fixing your work.

As *Rob* had pointed out below, IE is outdated and most versions lack HTML5 compatibility, so you will have to come up with solutions if you're going to be making cross-browser compatible sites.

Comment: He shouldn't have to adjust markup or CSS for IE's sake. If the markup is valid, then IE is the problem. (Of course, IE is always a problem)

Comment: @Rob I agree with you there. IE is always the problem, but a good developer always makes his work cross-browser compatible, and that's what he's asking us to help him with.

Comment: But I don't agree he should change working markup for IE's sake. There are other methods like those you show. (Whenever anyone says, "cross-browser compatible" they always mean "make it work in IE".)

Comment: I still dont know how to fix it, it's problem with IE, the rospan dont work good.

Comment: Rob, that is also true as Opera, Firefox, Chrome even Safari beat IE in compatibility, but there are still a bunch of "old ladies" who can't tell the difference. If he is going to be working on a actual website, or at least the start of it, he should be thinking about IE as well. Otherwise there is really no point as you said earlier :) @NirBe you read through my post and try everything?

Comment: Yes, and it's still with this problem.

Comment: `border-collapse:collapse;`

Answer (score 0):

I think it because IE will try and fill the remaining space it sees

instead of using rowspan

try using height="33%" or height="66%"

or try both

Comment: @NirBe have you also tried applying `border-collapse:collapse;`? This might keep the borders from sliding up and down in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Define height for each row like this:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%; height: 100%">
    <tr style="height: 33%">
        <td style="width: 46%" colspan="2"></td>
        <td style="width: 23%; padding-top: 0.5%" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td style="width: 23%; padding-top: 0.5%" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 33%">
        <td style="width: 23%" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td style="width: 23%" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 33%">
        <td style="width: 46%" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Tested on IE8 and IE 11